# long press super key for keyboard shortcuts doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, vmware, mac, shortcuts

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Macbook pro running in VMware fusion.  Right now keyboard shortcuts don't appear after long-press of super key.  I'm curious if anyone has figured out how to do this?